# Nav not fixed at top of page after scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a script to work which will fix the nav element at the top of the page when you scroll down the page to the nav tag. However what it is doing now is that is starts fixing at the top of the page only when your have scrolled down half of the page well past the nav tag?  You can view the page in question [here](http://macreviewzone-archive.net/project/index.html)

**Script**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 25;
if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
$('nav').addClass('fixed');
 }
 else {
$('nav').removeClass('fixed');
 }
});
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<nav id="nav_desktop"> 

<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dt">Downtown Tour</a></li>
    <li><a href="#gt">Growth Tour</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lt">Landmarks Tour</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ct">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
height: 25px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: `var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 25;` makes navHeight equal to the entire height of the window, minus 25 pixels, so when you're scrolling, the nav won't get fixed until a full window's worth of content has passed by.

Answer (score 1):

`var navHeight = $(window).height() - 25;`

This line won't fix your nav to the top as you would expect. It just gets the window height and subtracts it by 25.

You first need to get the `offsetTop` value of the `nav` bar to check if the `scrollTop` value of the window reaches the `offsetTop` of the `nav` bar.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var navTop = $('.nav').position().top; // returns and assigns the offset top of the nav bar

        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= navTop) { // condition met if the scroll top value is greater than or equal to the offset top of the nav bar
                $('nav').addClass('fixed');
            }
            else if($(window).scrollTop() < navTop) { //condition met if the scroll top value is only lower than the offset top of the nav bar
                $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yeah. Sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the navbar in your site is fixing if you scroll down at the bottom of the page. so if you want it to be fixed once the navbar scrolls out of viewport you can try the following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var navHeight = $( 'nav' ).offset().top;
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
                $('nav').addClass('fixed');
            }
            else {
                $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `$('nav').offset().top;` gets the top position of the navbar with respect to the document's top position. So once you scroll more than that value, the `fixed` class is added to it.

Also I would recommend you to change some css property of `fixed` class. you should keep it as follows:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 88%;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

You have to set width(88% in your navbar's case) to the fixed positioned elements as `position:fixed` takes the width according to the content of the div and not the full width.

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked to an exetent. However once the nav element had fixed if you scrolled any further down the whole page would shake .... Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Try to add `var navHeight = $( 'nav' ).offset().top;` before the `$(window).bind('scroll', function() {` line. Hope it helps you.

Comment: You're welcome. Will edit it in  the answer as well.